# Where does Voldemort get the body from?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

When Voldemort created Horcruxes, he divided the soul into it. Once he died only soul was present.

Then from where exactly his body came from? Peter Pettigrew used Harry's Blood but whose flesh he used to bring back Voldemort?

Comment: Addressed by JKR. In short it's a horrible thing that she doesn't want to mention because it's a book for children.

Comment: I don’t think this is a duplicate. The linked questions are about a different stage.

Answer (score -3):

Voldemort’s body was generated by a particular piece of Dark Magic. From his own description:

> I set my sights lower . . . I would settle for my old body back again, and my old strength.
>
> “I knew that to achieve this—it is an old piece of Dark Magic, the potion that revived me tonight—I would need three powerful ingredients. Well, one of them was already at hand, was it not, Wormtail? Flesh given by a servant. . . .
>
> “My father’s bone, naturally, meant that we would have to come here, where he was buried. But the blood of a foe . . . Wormtail would have had me use any wizard, would you not, Wormtail? Any wizard who had hated me . . . as so many of them still do. But I knew the one I must use, if I was to rise again, more powerful than I had been when I had fallen. I wanted Harry Potter’s blood. I wanted the blood of the one who had stripped me of power thirteen years ago . . . for the lingering protection his mother once gave him would then reside in my veins too. . . .

When we first see the potion it seems to be just liquid:

> Then he came back within Harry’s range of vision, and Harry saw him pushing a stone cauldron to the foot of the grave. It was full of what seemed to be water—Harry could hear it slopping around—and it was larger than any cauldron Harry had ever used; a great stone belly large enough for a full-grown man to sit in.

Judging from it’s reaction to the fire, there may have been something else besides water, but we are not told what:

> The liquid in the cauldron seemed to heat very fast. The surface began not only to bubble, but to send out fiery sparks, as though it were on fire. Steam was thickening, blurring the outline of Wormtail tending the fire. The movements beneath the robes became more agitated. And Harry heard the high, cold voice again.

Then Wormtail adds Voldemort’s current form:

> It was as though Wormtail had flipped over a stone and revealed something ugly, slimy, and blind—but worse, a hundred times worse. The thing Wormtail had been carrying had the shape of a crouched human child, except that Harry had never seen anything less like a child. It was hairless and scaly-looking, a dark, raw, reddish black. Its arms and legs were thin and feeble, and its face—no child alive ever had a face like that—flat and snakelike, with gleaming red eyes.
>
> And then Wormtail lowered the creature into the cauldron; there was a hiss, and it vanished below the surface; Harry heard its frail body hit the bottom with a soft thud.

Then he adds the bone of Voldemort’s father:

> The surface of the grave at Harry’s feet cracked. Horrified, Harry watched as a fine trickle of dust rose into the air at Wormtail’s command and fell softly into the cauldron.

And his own right hand:

> He stretched his right hand out in front of him—the hand with the missing finger. He gripped the dagger very tightly in his left hand and swung it upward. Harry realized what Wormtail was about to do a second before it happened—he closed his eyes as tightly as he could, but he could not block the scream that pierced the night, that went through Harry as though he had been stabbed with the dagger too. He heard something fall to the ground, heard Wormtail’s anguished panting, then a sickening splash, as something was dropped into the cauldron.

And Harry’s blood:

> He felt its point penetrate the crook of his right arm and blood seeping down the sleeve of his torn robes. Wormtail, still panting with pain, fumbled in his pocket for a glass vial and held it to Harry’s cut, so that a dribble of blood fell into it.
>
> He staggered back to the cauldron with Harry’s blood. He poured it inside.

We don’t see any other ingredients. Thus, the flesh of Voldemort’s body apparently came from whatever was put into the potion, plus magic. Two of the ingredients contained flesh.